# RPG Character Simulator Creating Random Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently doing A level Computer Science and have been given a task which involves writing some code that randomly generates 10 creatures from subclasses to add into a list and save them to a file for printing and editing later. I have written some code in Python after doing a lot of research but cannot get it to generate any random creatures. I am very new to writing code but I do want to learn so I would be very grateful if anyone could point out where I am going wrong please.  Please see my code below.  Many thanks.

```
import textwrap
from random import randint
global randomness
global messages
import random
name = 'Barbarian', 'Elf', 'Wizard', 'Dragon', 'Knight'
syllables = [ 'Ga',  'Bu', 'Zo', 'Meu' ]

#to create generic character class
class Creature:
 def __init__(self, name, type, health=100, power=50, sap=20, speed=50):
  self.name = name
  self.type = type
  self.health = health
  self.power = power
  self.sap = sap
  self.speed = speed

def __str__(self):
 return textwrap.dedent(f"""\
Name: {self.name}
Type: {self.type}
Health: {self.health}
Power {self.power}
Sap {self.sap}
Speed {self.speed}\n""")

# to create creature subclasses

class Barbarian(Creature):
 def __init__(self, name, type="Barbarian", health=100, power=70, sap=20,            speed=50, **kwargs):
  super().__init__(name=name, type=type, health=health, power=power,   sap=sap, speed=speed, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
 return super().__str__()

class Elf(Creature):
 def __init__(self, name, type= "Elf", health=100, power=30, sap= 60,   speed=60,**kwargs):
  super().__init__(name=name, type=type, health=health, power=power, sap=sap, speed=speed, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
 return super().__str__()

class Wizard(Creature):
 def __init__(self, name, type= "Wizard", health=100, power=50, sap= 70, speed=30,**kwargs):
   super().__init__(name=name, type=type, health=health, power=power, sap=sap, speed=speed, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
 return super().__str__()

class Dragon(Creature):
 def __init__(self, name, type= "Dragon", health=100, power=90, sap= 40,    speed=50,**kwargs):
  super().__init__(name=name, type=type, health=health, power=power,   sap=sap, speed=speed, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
 return super().__str__()

class Knight(Creature):

 def __init__(self, name, type= "Knight", health=100, power=60, sap= 10, speed=60,**kwargs):
  super().__init__(name=name, type=type, health=health, power=power, sap=sap, speed=speed, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
 return super().__str__()

def mainmenu():
 print("1:name generator\n2:generate creatures\n3:print      creaturelist\n4:edit creaturelist")
 choice=input()
 return choice

choice = mainmenu()
while (choice != "1" and choice !="2" and choice !="3" and choice !="4"):
 choice = mainmenu()

if choice == "1":
  name = syllables[ random.randint( 0, 3 )], syllables[ random.randint( 0, 3 )], syllables[ random.randint( 0, 3 )]

print (name)
f = open("creaturelist.txt","w") #to open file and append name of creature
f.close() # to close file

if choice == "2":
# pick ten random creatures then store in a file
 @classmethod
 def get_random_instances(cls):
  return random.sample(cls.Creature, 10)
  f = open("creaturelist.txt","w") #to open text file and write list of creatures to it
  f.close() # to close text file

# to print creature list to the console
if choice == "3":
  with open("creaturelist.txt") as file:
   print (f.read)
   f.close()

# to open and write to text file to edit creaturelist and stats as required
if choice == "4":
  f = open("creaturelist.txt","w") #to open text file and write to file as required
  f.close()
```

Comment: May I see the output of `print(random.sample(cls.Creature, 10))`

Comment: `def __str__(self):
 return super().__str__()` is unnecessary because subclasses inherit the methods.

Comment: Maybe what you want to do with 'choice 2' is a "factory method pattern" : https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/ ?

Comment: Please, review you indentation ! Following python standard, you should have 4 spaces for each indentation.

Comment: Another general remark is that you should avoid using `type` as the name a variable, it is a reserved word in python !

Answer (score 1):

For "choice 1", it can be done like this:

```
if choice == "1":
  name = syllables[ random.randint( 0, 3 )], syllables[ random.randint( 0,     3 )], syllables[ random.randint( 0, 3 )]
  print (name)
  f = open("creaturelist.txt","w") #to open file and append name of creature
  f.write("".join(name))
  f.close() # to close file
```

`print()` shows a string on the terminal, not in the file (and you have first to open the file before writing to it).

For "choice 2", this will gives you 10 names of creature:

```
if choice == "2":
  print(random.choices(name, k=10))
```

The "choice 3" part should better be rewritten like this :

```
if choice == "3":
  f = open("creaturelist.txt")
  print(f.read())
  f.close()
```

Compared to the other part in the code, you mixed `f = open()` with `with open() as file` and you get lost (mixing `f` and `file`).

There are a lot more to say about your code...

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for all of your comments; I really appreciate the help.  This is the output of print(random.sample(cls.Creature, 10)):
'Barbarian', 'Elf', 'Wizard', 'Dragon', 'Knight')